# Checking nullable state of spans

Tags: java, foreach, iterator, jsoup, html-parsing

I've got two elements parsed with jsoup, both the same span:

```
span.icon-list__title
```

The problem is: The first span is always there, but the second might not be. I tried `for` loops, doing iterators checking for the first and then the next:

```
Iterator t = third.select("span.icon-list__title").iterator();
    if (t.hasNext()) {
        title_software = t.next().toString();
        //first behaviour
        while (t.hasNext()) {
            photo_time = t.next().toString();
        }
    }
```

But I always seem to get `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2 error`, because the span doesn't seem to exist. Is there any possible way to check if it exists before parsing it?
The problem is I have two seperate string values.

Basically I've got 3 `divs` of class `icon-list`, which can be nullable (do not exist), and each of those divs have two divs:

`icon-list__title` and `icon-list__infos`, except the third.
Is there anyway I could check if every item was null or not? I can't seem to be storing the items in proper string variables.

Only the third div has two spans of class `icon-list__title`.

Here's the HTML:

```
  <div class="icon-list">
   <div class="icon-list__icon">
      <i class="icon-expand"></i>
   </div>
   <div class="icon-list__content">
      <div class="icon-list__title">4000 x 2667 pixels</div>
      <div class="icon-list__infos">
         <span>3.0 MB</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="icon-list">
   <div class="icon-list__icon">
      <i class="icon-camera"></i>
   </div>
   <div class="icon-list__content">
      <div class="icon-list__title">
         450
      </div>
      <div class="icon-list__infos">
         <span>1</span>
         <span>2</span>
         <span>3</span>
         <span>4</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="icon-list">
   <div class="icon-list__icon">
      <i class="icon-info"></i>
   </div>
   <div class="icon-list__content">
      <span class="icon-list__title">
      Span span 1
      </span>
      <span class="icon-list__title">
      Span span 2
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Everything can be nullable.
Is it the best if I use a foreach loop and put everything in a recyclerview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this, very static code but might do the job:

```
Elements result = third.select("span.icon-list__title");
if (result.size() > 0) {
    title_software = result.get(0).toString();
}
if (result.size() > 1) {
    photo_time = result.get(1).toString();
}
System.out.println(title_software);
System.out.println(photo_time);
```